# Proving Termination in Coq

Tags: coq, termination

How can I prove termination for `size_prgm`? I tried, but can't come up with a well founded relation to pass to `Fix`.

```
Inductive Stmt : Set :=
| assign: Stmt
| if': (list Stmt) -> (list Stmt) -> Stmt.

Fixpoint size_prgm (p: list Stmt) : nat := 
  match p with
  | nil  => 0
  | s::t => size_prgm t +
            match s with
            | assign  => 1
            | if' b0 b1 => S (size_prgm b0 + size_prgm b1)
            end
  end.
```

Answer (score 3):

The termination oracle is quite better than what it used to be. Defining a function `sum_with` using `fold_left` and feeding it the recursive call to `size_prgm` works perfectly well.

```
Require Import List.

Inductive Stmt : Set :=
| assign: Stmt
| if': (list Stmt) -> (list Stmt) -> Stmt.

Definition sum_with {A : Type} (f : A -> nat) (xs : list A) : nat :=
  fold_left (fun n a => n + f a) xs 0.

Fixpoint size_prgm (p: Stmt) : nat := 
  match p with
  | assign    => 1
  | if' b0 b1 => sum_with size_prgm b1 + sum_with size_prgm b0
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, since I don't have much time right now (I'll try to get back to you later):
this is a really usual (and silly) problem that every Coq user has to experience one day.

If I recall correctly, there is two "general" solutions to this problem and lots of very specific ones. For the two former:

1. build a inner fixpoint: I don't really remember how to do this properly.
2. use a mutual recursive type: The issue with your code is that you use `list Stmt` in your `Stmt` type, and Coq is not able to compute the induction principle you have in mind. But you could use a time like

   ```
   Inductive Stmt : Set :=
     | assign : Stmt
     | if': list_Stmt -> list_Stmt -> Stmt
   with list_Stmt : Set :=
     | Nil_Stmt : list_Stmt
     | Cons_Stmt : Stmt -> list_Stmt -> list_Stmt.
   ```

Now write your function over this type and a bijection between this type and your original `Stmt` type.

You can try to browse the Coq-Club mailing list, this kind of topic is a recurring one.

Hope it helps a bit,
V