# Nested recursion with partial application

Tags: recursion, coq

I am trying to define a nested recursive function over two parameters in Coq.

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint map_sequence2 {A B C : Set} (f : A -> B -> option C)
  (xs : list A) (ys : list B) : option (list C) :=
match xs, ys with
| [], [] => Some []
| x :: xs, y :: ys =>
  match f x y, map_sequence2 f xs ys with
  | Some z, Some zs => Some (z :: zs)
  | _, _ => None
  end
| _, _ => None
end.

Inductive T : Set := TA | TB : list T -> T.

Definition max n m := if Nat.leb n m then m else n.

Fixpoint height (t : T) : nat :=
match t with
| TA => 1
| TB xs => 1 + List.fold_left max (List.map height xs) 0
end.

Function bar (t1 : T) (t2 : T) {measure height t2} : option T :=
match t1, t2 with
| TA, TA => Some TA
| TB xs, TB ys =>
  match map_sequence2 bar xs ys with
  | Some zs => Some (TB zs)
  | None => None
  end
| _, _ => None
end.
Proof.
Abort.
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: No such section variable or assumption: bar.

The documentation of `Function` explicitly says:

> Function does not support partial application of the function being defined.

But this is exactly my case. What is the the strategy for such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you slightly redefine the `map_sequence2` function (I just moved `fix` a bit to the right)

```
Definition map_sequence2 {A B C : Set} (f : A -> B -> option C) :=
  fix map_sequence2 (xs : list A) (ys : list B) : option (list C) :=
match xs, ys with
| [], [] => Some []
| x :: xs, y :: ys =>
  match f x y, map_sequence2 xs ys with
  | Some z, Some zs => Some (z :: zs)
  | _, _ => None
  end
| _, _ => None
end.
```

then the totality checker accepts your definition with just `Fixpoint` instead of `Function` or `Program Fixpoint`:

```
Fixpoint bar (t1 : T) (t2 : T) : option T :=
match t1, t2 with
| TA, TA => Some TA
| TB xs, TB ys =>
  match map_sequence2 bar xs ys with
  | Some zs => Some (TB zs)
  | None => None
  end
| _, _ => None
end.
```

This solution is just like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19517159/2747511) by @gallais. And if you `Print fold_left.` which is used in that solution, you'll see that it has been defined in the same style.

---

Let me add that this behavior of the totality checker is surprising for me. I stumbled upon this while trying to simplify your definition:

```
Section liftA2.
Variables A B C : Type.
Definition liftA2_option (f : A -> B -> C) : option A -> option B -> option C :=
  fun ox oy =>
    match ox, oy with
    | Some x, Some y => Some (f x y)
    | _, _ => None
    end.
End liftA2.
Arguments liftA2_option {A B C}.

Section Combine_with_option.
Variables A B C : Set.
Variable f : A -> B -> option C.

Fixpoint combine_with_option (xs : list A) (ys : list B) : option (list C) :=
  match xs,ys with
  | x::xs', y::ys' => liftA2_option cons (f x y) (combine_with_option xs' ys') 
  | [], [] => Some []
  | _, _ => None
  end.
End Combine_with_option.
Arguments combine_with_option {A B C}.

Fixpoint bar (t1 : T) (t2 : T) : option T :=
match t1, t2 with
| TA, TA => Some TA
| TB xs, TB ys =>
  match combine_with_option bar xs ys with
  | Some zs => Some (TB zs)
  | None => None
  end
| _, _ => None
end.
```

When one uses the section mechanism with `Fixpoint`s one gets `fix` after the "shared" (unchanged) parameters.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Is there some literature to get to know the termination oracle better?

Comment: There is [this description](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/gallina.html#sec57) in the manual. And, perhaps, [this Cocrico article](https://coq.inria.fr/cocorico/CoqTerminationDiscussion) might help.